# mock HttpClient SendAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

My code is using HttpClient in order to retrieve some data

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("myurl.com"),
};
var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "myendpoint");
var res = await client.SendAsync(msg);
```

how can I mock this SendAsync method on HttpClient and inject it inside .net core ServiceCollection?

I tried to mock like this

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
                .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent("{'name':thecodebuzz,'city':'USA'}"),
                });

            var client = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
            mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(client);
```

> but how to inject this mockFactory into ServiceCollection? Or maybe there is some easier or different way around?

Comment: Instead of mocking the HTTP call, why not encapsulate it? Then you can mock the encapsulation

Comment: @MattThomas sounds good, why don't you post the solution as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mocking the HTTP call, why not encapsulate it? Then you can mock the encapsulation/abstraction.

For example:

```cs
interface IClient
{
  Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

class HttpClientAdapter : IClient
{
  readonly HttpClient _client;

  public HttpClientAdapter(HttpClient client)
  {
    _client = client;
  }

  public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => _client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Make your code depend on the `IClient` interface. During normal usage you would use a real `HttpClient` in the `HttpClientAdapter` implementation. And for tests you could mock the `IClient`.

Note it might be more useful to you to make the abstraction a little higher level than this. For example, if you're expecting to parse a JSON string from HTTP responses into some `DataObject` then maybe your `IClient` interface should look more like this:

```cs
class DataObject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
}

interface IClient
{
  Task<DataObject> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public class ClientImplementation : IClient
{
  readonly HttpClient _client;

  public ClientImplementation(HttpClient client)
  {
    _client = client;
  }

  public async Task<DataObject> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(...);
    var dataObject = new DataObject();
    // parse the response into the data object
    return dataObject;
  }
}
```

The advantage of drawing the line here is your tests will have less work to do. Your mock code won't have to set up `HttpResponseMessage` objects, for example.

Where you choose to draw the boundaries for your abstractions is totally up to you. But the key takeaway is: once your code depends on a small interface then it's easy to mock that interface and test your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to mock the HttpClient itself, take a look at this lib:
https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp

From the docs:

```
var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();

// Setup a respond for the user api (including a wildcard in the URL)
mockHttp.When("http://localhost/api/user/*")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}"); // Respond with JSON

// Inject the handler or client into your application code
var client = mockHttp.ToHttpClient();

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/user/1234");
// or without async: var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/user/1234").Result;

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// No network connection required
Console.Write(json); // {'name' : 'Test McGee'}
```