# HttpClient mock

Tags: c#, xunit.net, .net-7.0

.NET 7, xUnit, moq

I get an error while testing this:

```
// Arrange
var mockHttpClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
var expectedResponseContent = "response content";

mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(expectedResponseContent)
    });

var httpClient = new HttpClientAdapter(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object)
{
    BaseAddress = new("https://stackoverflow.com")
};

mockHttpClientFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient("someClient"))
    .Returns(httpClient);

var controller = new SomeController(mockHttpClientFactory.Object);

// Act
var result = await controller.GetPayloadAsync();

// Assert
Assert.Equal(expectedResponseContent, result);
```

Error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Error while copying content to a stream.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a closed Stream.

Code I'm testing:

```
await client.GetStringAsync("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

In the test I started off just mocking `HttpClient` with `HttpClientFactory` but that showed the error. I then implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092506/955831).

but I still get the same error. Modified it like this:

```
class HttpClientAdapter : HttpClient, IClient
{
    public HttpClientAdapter(HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler): base(httpMessageHandler)
    {
    }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Any ideas how to test this without the stream being closed?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question but I would recommend taking a look at integration tests with WebApplicationFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0
You will get the http client for the application which you can and avoid mocking http stuff altogether.

Comment: @Edub I'm actual using that, but that's to test the endpoints of my application. Testing the action methods directly. Also, using MSAL for authentication and have no control over Azure AD.

Comment: An HTTP client makes only one connection  The client sends a request and then gets a response on the same connection and then closes.  For testing you can add a test mode to the request and then have server when in test mode return a test response instead of a real response.  You cannot keep the connection open after the response is sent.

Comment: @jdweng that actually looks like my issue. There is another call being made before the one I posted, hidden in another class.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the issue that @jdweng in the comments explained.
I needed to rewrite the Setup of SendAsync for 2 Http calls. Here is the code.

```
var handlerIndex = 0;

mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(() =>
    {
        if (handlerIndex == 0)
        {
            handlerIndex++; // Increment the index for the second call
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(expectedResponseContent1)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(expectedResponseContent2)
            };
        }
    })
    .Verifiable();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to use delegate in `.ReturnsAsync()` instead of direct value.

```
mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                .ReturnsAsync(() =>
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        Content = new StringContent(expectedResponseContent)
                    };
                });
```

I assume that is because in this case Moq executes the delegate code every time and as a result creates new `HttpResponseMessage()` object every time. In your case case `HttpResponseMessage()` created only once and as a result internal streams can contain incorrect state on subsequent calls.